# Jenkins Error Loading FIle from Artifacts

Tags: jenkins, terraform

I created a build pipeline that's takes Artifacts from an Upstream Project A and copies it into downstream Project B. My system has all the build artifacts archived, but for some reason Jenkins isn't loading up those files to the directory it's running the build in. I keep getting the below error message when I try to run my shell commands. I'm running Jenkins on vagrant so i'm not sure if this has anything to do it but was curious if anyone has come across this.

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/tf-deploy/workspace
Promoting tf-deploy #43
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson7656233371468187886.sh
+ terraform show -module-depth=-1 tfplan
[31mError loading file: open tfplan: no such file or directory[0m[0m
failed build hudson.tasks.Shell@1310c10d SUCCESS
Warning: this build has no associated authentication, so build permissions may be lacking, and downstream projects which cannot even be seen by an anonymous user will be silently skipped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

A little more detail about how you are doing the copy would help.  I don't see anything in the output showing things being copied.

Perhaps you want to use the [Clone Workspace Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clone+Workspace+SCM+Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

So after further review it appears that the upstream job did infact keep the artifacts, but the downstream job never copied over the artifacts. After updating the build to copy over the artifacts from the previous build everything worked nicely. Being up till 3AM and nodding off didn't help the situation :)